# I can't execute ./bin/elasticsearch on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, bash, java

When I run `./bin/elasticsearch` command, I get the following error:

```
./bin/elasticsearch-cli: line 14: /home/samira/elasticsearch-8.4.2/jdk/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
./bin/elasticsearch-cli: line 14: /home/samira/elasticsearch-8.4.2/jdk/bin/java: Success
```

This is my elasticsearch-cli:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -o pipefail

source "`dirname "$0"`"/elasticsearch-env

# use a small heap size for the CLI tools, and thus the serial collector to
# avoid stealing many CPU cycles; a user can override by setting CLI_JAVA_OPTS
CLI_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC ${CLI_JAVA_OPTS}"

LAUNCHER_CLASSPATH=$ES_HOME/lib/*:$ES_HOME/lib/cli-launcher/*

exec \
  "$JAVA" \
  $CLI_JAVA_OPTS \
  -Dcli.name="$CLI_NAME" \
  -Dcli.script="$0" \
  -Dcli.libs="$CLI_LIBS" \
  -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" \
  -Des.path.conf="$ES_PATH_CONF" \
  -Des.distribution.type="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_TYPE" \
  -cp "$LAUNCHER_CLASSPATH" \
  org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher \
  "$@"
```

I run `java -version` and it outputs:

```
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode)
```

Then I run `lscpu` and it outputs:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           94
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         1098.724
CPU max MHz:                     3600.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        6399.96
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        6 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Mitigation; IBRS
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Mitigation; TSX disabled
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss 
                                 ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_
                                 tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1
                                  sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault
                                  invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx s
                                 map clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window h
                                 wp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. It makes it easier to read and allows for searching the text.

Comment: this seems to be a wrong JDK installed on your system, could you please run `lscpu` and `java -version` and add the output to your question?

Comment: I edited my question and added error @David

Comment: how can I run `lscpu` and `java -version`@Amirreza

Comment: open a terminal, run the first command `lscpu`, and send the output so that we could see what architecture your cpu is, then run `java -version` to find out what java version and architecture is installed. https://mkyong.com/java/bash-usr-bin-java-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error/ may help you as well

Comment: I ran `lscpu` and  `java -version` then I edited my question@Amirreza

Comment: from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch, the correct version to download is `deb x86_64`, is that what you downloaded?

Comment: yes I used from this command `wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.4.2-linux-aarch64.tar.gz`

Comment: and that's exactly the issue :) your CPU architecture is x86_64 not aarch64, I'll fill and answer

Comment: ok all right, but how can I fix this issue??   Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 5):

Your CPU architecture is `x86_64` while the downloaded elastic-search is `aarch64`

<del>go to the *elasticsearch* directory, open a terminal there and run `./uninstall.sh` to uninstall the current `aarch64` version, then install the correct release;</del>

there are two releases for that architecture you can download, one is a `.tar.gz` file and the other a `.deb` file, `.deb` installation files are easier to install and also easier to uninstall, so the correct version to install is either the [elasticsearch-8.4.2-amd64.deb](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.4.2-amd64.deb) (recommended) or [elasticsearch-8.4.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.4.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz)

I suggest the first one

Comment: this link can be helpful to uninstall: https://www.netbraintech.com/docs/ie80/help/uninstalling-elasticsearch.htm

Comment: I test your answer but I get this error!!!`ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly`

Comment: does it happen when uninstalling it? in which phase?

Comment: my bad @samirapadidar, elastic search isn't actually installed in your system as you could not run the installer (because it's a different unsupported architecture), so ignore the "uninstalling" part and just install the `.deb` file

Comment: Hi Amirreza thanks for your answers I successed to install elasticserch and kibana and actived them but now I dont know what is my passwort for user 'elastic'!!! I be a liitle confused becaus Im so beginer in elasticsearch

Comment: I run `curl https://localhost:9200 --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic`

Comment: then I get `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey","Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey","Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""]}},"status":401}`

Comment: I think this for wrong password. Where can I find the password?

Comment: @samirapadidar this is another issue that needs a separate thread probably in stack-overflow, I'll be happy if you mark my answer as correct :)